# DFP - Line item is delivering but ad slot is empty

Tags: google-dfp

I just noticed this problem, one of my line items is still delivering, confirmed from the status in DFP, but one of the slots defined in this line item isn't showing the creative. I am not sure why this is happening as I am pretty sure the code and configuration is correct as the ad used to be showing in that slot.

Does anyone have any idea where I should begin to debug?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you ever end up finding a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue on one of my client's sites.

Comment: @Tspesh No, looks more like an intermittent issue. It's been a while now and now the site looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the output of the DFP console?

Have a look at this page here: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/181070?hl=en

Using the console you should be able to see if there are any problems with the delivery of your line item or creative.

Comment: Thanks. But I checked in the console, the ad slot says it's fetching one object but the render time is 0. I checked the delivery diagnostics and opened the creative in the new tab, they all seem to be fine.